# a strategy to partition a set to get the minimum sum of variances from subsets

Tags: python, algorithm, statistics

The problem is:
I have a set of numbers, and I need to divide it into k subsets. I have to find the best partition strategy to get the minimum sum of the variance from each subsets. No subset can be empty
(The variance is the square of standard deviation.)

k is an integer greater than 0.
The approximation can be 1e+7

This is my solution so far, which works for some examples, but not always:

1. sort the sample (a set of numbers) in ascending order.
2. compute the distance of two continuous elements. Construct a list of lists, the sublist has the index of left element and distance  (i.e. [[idx, dist], [idx, dist]......]). sort the list in descending order by distance.
3. use the indices in the list I have, get indices from left to right to partition the ascending sorted sample

Python code:

```
class MinimumVariancePartition(object):
    def minDev(self, mixedSamples, k):
        # mixedSamples is a tuple, k is an integer.

        samples_ascending = sorted(mixedSamples)

        # Build a list of lists contains indices and distances.
        idx_dist = []
        for index in range(len(samples_ascending) - 1):
            starting_idx = index
            dist = abs(samples_ascending[index] - samples_ascending[index + 1])
            idx_dist.append([starting_idx, dist])

        sorted_idx_dist = sorted(idx_dist, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

        # Get a list of indices to split the sample.
        split_idx = []
        for i in range(k - 1):
            split_idx.append(sorted_idx_dist[i][0])

        # Get a list of subsets.    
        partitions = []
        if len(split_idx) == 0:
            partitions.append(mixedSamples)
        else:
            split_idx = sorted(split_idx)
            prev = 0
            for idx in split_idx:
                partitions.append(samples_ascending[prev:idx + 1])
                prev = idx + 1
            partitions.append(samples_ascending[prev:])

        # Compute the sum of variances
        result = 0
        for partition in partitions:
            variance = self.variance(partition)
            result += variance
        return result

    def variance(self, partition):
        # Compute variance of a subset
        size = len(partition)
        s = sum(partition)
        mean = float(s) / size
        variance = 0
        for n in partition:
            temp = round(n - mean, 14)**2  # use round() to avoid float number 'trick'
            variance += temp
        variance /= size
        return variance
```

tests passed:

```
input: (3, 4, 7, 10), 1
output: 7.5

input: (1000,500,1,500), 3
output: 0.0

input: (42,234,10,1,123,545,436,453,74,85,34,999), 5
output: 1700.7397959183672
```

tests failed:

```
input: (197, 611, 410, 779, 203, 15, 727, 446, 992, 722, 439, 296, 201, 820, 416, 272, 89, 146, 687, 203, 598, 65, 865, 945, 446, 783, 581, 270, 960, 22, 970, 698, 456, 706, 14, 901, 371, 688, 914, 925, 551, 15, 326, 620, 842, 82, 594, 99, 827, 660), 21
expected output: 757.3225
actual output: 824.586388889

input: (359, 408, 124, 89, 26, 878, 677, 341, 166, 434, 886, 539, 227, 420, 655, 330, 835, 378, 763, 401, 883, 332, 215, 424, 365, 841, 113, 825, 777, 969, 970, 668, 602, 708, 874, 930, 423, 549, 236), 13
expected output: 1588.0486111111109
actual output: 2163.79166667

input: (706, 835, 160, 432, 148, 472, 26, 917, 736, 342, 442, 479, 95, 800, 956), 4
expected output: 8172.465
actual output: 11259.875
```

I am thinking the problem in my solution might be in the finding partition index step, but still don't know why it doesn't work.

Comment: What specifically is going wrong? Can you provide an example where you know what the output should be and what output the computations yield?

Comment: @theWanderer4865 I have added sample inputs and outputs, thank you!

Comment: Am I right in interpreting your problem is needing to simply break each set into proper subsets with respect to the variance BETWEEN the values in a subset?

Comment: @theWanderer4865 correct! each variance is from every subset

Comment: This paper proposes a `O(n^2 k)` algorithm that solves the problem of minimizing the unnormalized variance (the paper calls it "withinness"). https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5148156/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because the idea of your algorithm is not correct(splitting taking into account only the distance between two adjacent elements does not always yield an optimal solution).

You can use dynamic programming instead:
1. Sort the array.
2. Let's assume that `f(first_free, sets_count)` is the minimum sum of variances if the `first_free` element is the first element that has not been added to any set yet and exactly `sets_count` sets have already been created.
3. The base case is `f(0, 0) = 0`. It corresponds to an empty prefix.
4. Transitions look this way:

```
for first_free = 0 ... n - 1:
    for new_first_free = first_free + 1 ... n:
        for sets_count = 0 ... k - 1:
            f(new_first_free, sets_count + 1) = min(f(new_first_free, sets_count + 1),
                f(first_free, sets_count) + variance of the subset [first_free, new_first_free - 1])
```

5. The answer `f(n, k)`(where `n` is the number of elements in the set).

Here is my implementation(it can be optimized, it's just a sketch, but it works properly):

```
a = [706, 835, 160, 432, 148, 472, 26, 917, 736, 342, 442, 479, 95, 800, 956]
k = 4
mem = dict()
INF = 1e10


def get_variance(partition):
    size = len(partition)
    s = sum(partition)
    mean = float(s) / size
    variance = 0
    for n in partition:
        temp = round(n - mean, 14) ** 2
        variance += temp
    variance /= size
    return variance


def calc(pos, cnt):
    if (pos, cnt) in mem.keys():
        return mem[(pos, cnt)]
    if pos == 0 and cnt >= 0:
        return 0.0
    if cnt < 0:
        return INF
    res = INF
    for old_pos in range(0, pos):
        res = min(res, calc(old_pos, cnt - 1) + get_variance(a[old_pos: pos]))
    mem[(pos, cnt)] = res
    return res


if __name__ == '__main__':
    a.sort()
    print(calc(len(a), k))
```

Comment: This is a correct explanation of what's going wrong: you're using a "nearest neighbor" approach to the problem. That, however, will not always work because, as the answerer says, because the optimal solution to this problem requires "trying" a lot of alternatives. You can check out dynamic programming in python from [here](http://jeremykun.com/2012/01/12/a-spoonful-of-python/) you can also find a lot of resources on the "Knapsack Problem" and the Travelling Salesman problem, both of which have solutions that result from dynamic programming.

Comment: Thank you! Should you set f(0, 0) as infinite? In the first iteration, can I interpret it as f(1, 1) = min(f(1, 1), f(0, 0) + 0)? So the answer would always be 0?   @user2040251

Comment: @ChesterL I added a Python implementation. You can see how boundary cases are handled there.

Comment: Could you please explain the reason to sort the array? @user2040251

Comment: @ChesterL Dynamic programming works correctly here only if a resulting partition always consists of contiguous subarrays. It is true if and only if the array is sorted.